# What is the head Node of a linked lists? Is it the first Node or a reference to it?

Tags: java, linked-list

Having trouble understanding linked lists. This is in java. I am writing some methods, add, remove, find. But wondering here, is Head, which is defined as a type Node the actual first Node? does it contain data and a next Node reference? Or does it somehow tell what the data is of the first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `head` node is the first node in the list. The `tail` node is the last node in the list.

There's nothing special about either of them.

In your `LinkedList` class you might have references to `head` and `tail`, but the nodes themselves are just nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, not limited to Java, all list nodes are the same, and the "head" node is the first one on the list.  This, "head", is usually a variable that is a *reference* (or a *pointer*) to the first list node.

A simple singly-linked-list node may look like

```
class ListNode
{
    Object data;      // The data added to the list
    ListNode next;    // Reference to the next item in the list
}
```

Then "head" would just be

```
ListNode head;
```

that is, a variable named "head" that holds (a reference to) a ListNode.
The issue gets somewhat confused in Java because everything (except primitives like `int`) is a *reference* — so this looks like *"head is a ListNode"* when it's actually *"head is a reference to a list node"*.

Pictorially, this is like the following, where I've put the "data" in parens and show "next" pointing to something.

```
head -> ListNode("foo")next -> ListNode("bar")next -> ListNode("baz")next -> null
```

The end of the list is found when `next` holds the `null` value.  You would have to also have a `ListNode tail;` which would be updated to point to the last thing added to the list.

Here's an *extremely* simple (and untested) example of the concepts. Java's own `java.util.LinkedList` is much more complicated, and is parameterized with generics.

```
class List
{
    ListNode head = null;
    ListNode tail = null;

    public add(Object o)
    {
        ListNode node = new ListNode(o);
        if (head == null) head = node;         // if there's no head yet this is the head
        if (tail != null) tail.next = node;    // if there's a tail point tail at this new node
        tail = node;                           // and this is the new tail
    }
    // need remove() etc other methods
}
```